# Fullscreen image is not looking good on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, fullscreen

My website http://asebratenpark.no got a Home-page (main index-file) with fullscreen photos. I really like how it look on desktops. But really dislike how it looks on smartphones.

I am thinking of using queries to remove the fullscreen rules from firing on smartphones.

Is that an idea? If it is, I am a bit uncertain of how I should proceed.

Comment: what do you dislike about it? You can use CSS Media queries to display alternative images / graphics at certain resolutions (well, window sizes) if that's what you're meaning?

Comment: If you try to narrow the screen with, you can see that the picture stretches way out from the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions:

1) Use Media Queries in CSS to load a smaller image (you should be doing this anyway) so that something like:

```
@media only screen
and  (max-width: 640px)
{
    .background {
        background-image:url('ultrasmall.jpg');
    }
}
@media only screen
and (min-width : 641px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
   .background {
    background-image:url('smaller.jpg');
    } 
}
```

etc. for other screen / window sizes .

2)

You can also use CSS3 image sizing rules to set the image to fit the size of the screen so using `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` to best suit your needs.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
@media only screen
    and  (max-width: 640px)
    {
        .background {
            background-image:url('ultrasmall.jpg');
            background-size:cover;
        }
    }
```